# Light rays in cycles (as an emission shader) reflecting off of edge of the mesh

Tags: animation, lighting, emission

I have a weird problem. I followed a tutorial that showed how to set up a light beam using a cone mesh and a mapped emission shader. It looks great, except for one thing: the light keeps reflecting off of the circle on the cone, creating an unwanted red circle. I want the outer edge of the cone to be transparent, then have a gradual transition to a neon red towards the point of the cone (which is attached to a police car). I have tried playing around with a light path node which seems to yield a little better result but the red circle is still very apparent.

If i need to upload my project file then I can do that as well.
If any other info is needed please let me know, and thanks in advance!

The half red circle is on the left beam. It doesn't look too obvious now, but when I rendered out the animation, it stuck out like a sore thumb.
[image]
Computer system: M1 Mac Mini 16gb ram

Renderer: Cycles

Samples: 200

EDIT: Here is a link to the project file showing just the cones, lighting, and floor/wall if someone wants to test:

[image]

Comment: I don't know the tutorial, so it would be helpful to see the material setup for this cone. Trying something similar myself I didn't get this circle at the end, no matter if I'm using Eevee or Cycles (btw, you're doing it in Eevee I guess from the image?). Could you provide a screenshot of the material node tree or may upload not necessarily everything but a file with the cone here: https://blend-exchange.com/ (follow instructions there and paste the generated html in your question)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ok thanks, I've added the link in my question :) also I'm rendering this out in Cycles, and i noticed the red circle appears as sampling is being processed, which could be a small clue, but I figured 200 samples would be good enough for the quality i want without sacrificing performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the planes in the background seem to be the reason the red circle shows up, but I actually have no idea why. When you disable them in Render, the circle disappears as well.

However, that's not the only thing that helps. I used a slightly different material setup in the *Texture Coordinate* and the *Gradient Texture* and now the circle is gone.

[image: siren beam]

[image]

Comment: Oh perfect, thank you so much kind sir! Time to replay the rendering game lol

Comment: @SweetStorm You're welcome. I'm quite sure the original problem has something to do with the fact that the cone scale isn't applied in combination with the sheared end of the cone and Quadratic Sphere gradient. But simply applying scale didn't help and I didn't want to change your model too much, so I just used a material that works. You might consider accepting the answer then 